# how do you setup apache web server in netbeans 6.8?

Tags: netbeans, apache2

I'd like to debug PHP apps, but I want to setup Apache web server (httpd.exe).

I right clicked SERVERS, Add Server..., then noticed there is no option for httpd.exe, just for Glashfiish, JBoss, Apache Tomcat, and some other servers.

So, how can I add Apache Web Server (right from within the IDE just like other servers), and then properly debug PHP apps?

Comment: You might try asking this on serverfault.com, since it's more of a server question than a programming one.

Comment: it is about how to properly setup a programming environment for debugging and it is about an IDE, did you see those tags (apache2, netbeans6.8)? i did not create them :)

Comment: @JYelton, please see [“Belongs on” comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/belongs-on-comments), to avoid people are reposting questions while in fact they will be migrated automatically, if 5 people vote to do so. Thanks!

Comment: @Arjan, Hasn't been migrated yet... Voting to move questions should be allowed earlier!

Comment: @JYelton, my point is that comments like yours introduce duplicates, which can simply be avoided by either not commenting, or by commenting *"In the future please ask these kind of question on [..]. But don't repost this yourself; this question will be moved automatically if applicable."* The choice is yours ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans does not have a plugin to integrate the IDE with the Apache HTTP server directly.

The servers that are listed in the 'Add Server' dialog are all Java EE servers.  Since Apache is not a Java EE server, it is appropriate that it does not appear in that list.

That said, there are a number of [articles about the ins and outs of doing PHP development with NetBeans and Apache](http://netbeans.org/kb/trails/php.html).

It looks like you do not need to 'register' the httpd in NetBeans.  The PHP development plugins are supposed to take care of doing the right thing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Check it [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/debugging.html)

Comment: that instruction helps debugging, but does not solve the situation of registering Apache Web Server to the list of Servers...anyway, thanks because i may be able to debug PHP